# how to compress a very large SQLite database in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating an android application that uses an existing database (only text) but the problem is that my db is too large (about 130 MB) i tried compressing it (.zip -> 42 MB) but it's still too large  is there any way to make it smaller .....

Comment: Put a web service in front of your DB and have the android app pull just the data it needs via the network?

Comment: In theory everything is in pi number, even your db. Pi can be approximated on device... So you dont need to provide db with your app, you can calculate it :)

Comment: Effective compression is data dependent. Only having knowledge about data nature I can speculate about it's compressibility.

Answer (score 2):

If your database contains indexes, ship it without indexes, and create them after unpacking the database file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compress your file into .obb file. Use for that jobb.exe

Comment: How do you intend to decompress it on Android? Android has no jobb.exe!

Comment: But if you use external database and it is too big then you decompress it on the external server and pass compressed database into Android. Chloe, there is nothing wrong with my answer. As I can see marking my answer as not useful is very easy for you.

Comment: You have to state that in your answer. In which case it is a copy of JacobM's comment directly below the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compress with bzip2 which is the best compression so far, then decompress it when the app starts with Apache Bzip2 library:

http://javadoc.haefelinger.it/org.apache.ant/1.7.1/org/apache/tools/bzip2/CBZip2InputStream.html

http://www.kohsuke.org/bzip2/

```
$ ls -l
-rwx------+ 1 Chloe None 181248 Feb 10  2013 development.sqlite3
-rwx------+ 1 Chloe None   8560 Feb 10  2013 development.sqlite3.bz2
-rw-r--r--+ 1 Chloe None  11306 Oct 30 15:48 development.sqlite3.gz
-rwx------+ 1 Chloe None   8583 Feb 10  2013 development.sqlite3.lzma
```

Comment: Imho, lzma is better... And this is why this question is offtopic

Comment: `LZMA is generally more space-efficient than bzip2` from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2 - 181248 bytes is too small to compare if you have to compress more than 100MB ... http://tukaani.org/lzma/benchmarks.html

Comment: @Selvin But does it have an Android compatible library?

Comment: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: @Selvin Oh! LZMA = 7z! You should put that as an answer then. BTW not all Java libraries are compatible with Android.  Android uses a subset of the JDK.